# How to respond to websocket disconnect with React

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am trying to create a WebSocket client using React.  I have adapted code from https://github.com/bitlabstudio/blogpost-react-websocket-chat/blob/master/frontend/src/Chat.js to create a WebSocket listener component as follows:

```
class WsListen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        lastMessage: '',
        ws: null
      }
    }

  componentDidMount() {

    let ws = new WebSocket(URL)
    this.setState({ws: ws})

    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }

    ws.onmessage = evt => {
      console.log(evt.data)
      this.setState({lastMessage: evt.data})
    }

    ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log('disconnected')
      // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
      this.setState({ws: new WebSocket(URL)})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Last message: {this.state.lastMessage}</p>
      </div>
      );
    };
}
```

This works fine for creating a connection and listening to messages.  However, the logic to reconnect when the server sends a disconnect doesn't work.  On the server, I can see that the client has reconnected and been registered by the server.  But after the disconnection and reconnection, messages are no longer detected or responded to by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ws` no longer has `onmessage` function. You can create a `WebSocket` factory method and call it when new `ws` is needed.

```
createWebSocket = URL => {

    let ws = new WebSocket(URL);
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }

    ws.onmessage = evt => {
      console.log(evt.data)
      this.setState({lastMessage: evt.data})
    }

    ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log('disconnected')
      // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
      this.setState({ws: this.createWebSocket(URL)})
    }

return ws;
}

componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({ws: this.createWebSocket(URL)})

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.